# Invalid conversion from char to const char*

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-ide

Sorry in advance for what I feel is going to be a really simple problem, but I've been stuck on it for hours and I haven't been able to work out how to fix it based on the stuff I've found here or on google.

I've got an arduino hooked up to a GPS and a radio and am trying to broadcast the GPS signal to my radio. What I am trying to do now is get the NMEA sentence from the GPS into the variable 'text', but am getting confused by this error, which I think is due to arrays.

My error is occurring on this line:
`sprintf(text, char(c));`

I've tried a few different things but this is where I'm stuck at the moment. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
#define RADIOPIN 13
#include <string.h>
#include <util/crc16.h>
#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2);

#define GPSECHO  true

Adafruit_GPS GPS(&mySerial);

char datastring[80];
char text[80];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  GPS.begin(9600);
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCGGA);
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_5HZ);
  delay(3000);  
  pinMode(RADIOPIN,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  gpscheck();
}

void gpscheck(){
    char c = GPS.read();
    if (c) {
//      Serial.print(c); 
    sprintf(text, char*(c));
    Serial.print(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: `GPS.read()` will only return one character or a string?

Comment: `sprintf(text, char*(c));` is wrong! Read about it's usage [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read a reference of [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Then you will see that the second argument is a *string*.

So the following would be fine:

```
sprintf(text, "%c", c);
```

To be on the safe side, you might want to use `snprintf` instead, to lessesn the risk of buffer overflows.

Of course, for a single character, you might as well do e.g.

```
text[0] = c;
text[1] = '\0';  /* Terminate string */
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd been playing around with that as well and had tried:
sprintf(text, "%d", c);

Which is what I'd got from the sprintf documentation. I know realise it changes with the type of variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
sprintf(text, char*(c));
```

If you want to print character

```
simply use printf("%c",c);
```

if you want to copy that into text

```
sprintf(text,"%c", c);
```